# Date not showing in proper format in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

hi i want to display the date in MM/dd/yyyy format but it is showing '-' instead of '/'

```
$(function () {
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

if (isFirefox)
{
    $('#DateOfBooking').val('@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")');
}
else
{
    $('#DateOfBooking').val('@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")');
}});
```

Even if i open it in firefox it showing me date in MM-dd-yyyy format

Comment: Why the C# tag? It was removed for a reason.

Comment: @Equalsk Because of `'@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")'`

Comment: if you are using this code cshtml then try searching solution for date format conversion in C# instead of jQuery.

Comment: @Andreas I want to learn why this is considered C# but I don't know the keyword to search for when researching. Is this something specific to MVC? Does calling a C# function inside jQuery like this have a name?

Comment: @Equalsk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor

Comment: @Andreas Much appreciated, thank you.